# PostgreSQL: upsert function retries to insert infinitely

Tags: postgresql, infinite-loop, upsert, postgresql-9.4

Although I have seen that `upsert` will be part of `Postgresql 9.5`, I'm trying to write mine (I work with `PostgreSQL 9.4`) and I don't understand what I get an infinite recursion: the function retry to insert the row infinitely.

The problem appears when I try to return the id of the row that already exists in case of a `unique violation` (i.e. if I return `VOID`, it works).

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsertAddress(
  geographicPointValue      VARCHAR(63),
  cityValue                 VARCHAR(127),
  zipValue                  VARCHAR(15),
  streetValue               VARCHAR)
  RETURNS INT AS
  $$
  DECLARE addressIdToReturn int;
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      UPDATE addresses
        SET geographicPoint = POINT(geographicPointValue), city = cityValue, zip = zipValue, street = streetValue
        WHERE city = cityValue AND zip = zipValue AND street = streetValue;
      IF found THEN
        SELECT addressId INTO addressIdToReturn
          FROM addresses
          WHERE city = cityValue AND zip = zipValue AND street = streetValue;
        RETURN addressIdToReturn;
      END IF;
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO addresses (geographicPoint, city, zip, street)
          VALUES (POINT(geographicPointValue), cityValue, zipValue, streetValue)
          RETURNING addressId INTO addressIdToReturn;
        RETURN addressIdToReturn;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why a Loop at the beginning of the function?

Comment: It is explained here: http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/ (it is about race condition)

Comment: Don't do an `UPDATE` then `SELECT`; use `UPDATE ... RETURNING ... INTO` instead.

Comment: What isolation level is this running under?

Comment: Thanks for the first advice, you're right, it is a bit stupid, particularly because I use it few lines later. For the second comment I didn't change the isolation level so it still should be the PostgreSQL 9.4 standard.